# Testing boolean value from resource, and modify it accordingly? (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Suppose I have this in my window's resource:
    <System:Boolean x:Key="MyBool" />

Now how do I test it for its value? I've tried triggers etc but seem to further confuse myself.

More specifically how do I change its value when a button is clicked?
And how do I bind to the boolean resource, so when its value changes, some codes will be executed? (Using Triggers?)

**Note**: I do not want any code-behinds, I wish to do this in pure XAML.

Thank you for your time reading this :P

Comment: Why on earth would you need such thing?

Comment: Don't worry ^^ I wasn't fully awake when I made this question. Hence the reason why I couldn't solve it. It's all good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Now how do I test it for its value?*

In Xaml: `{StaticResource MyBool}`
In Code-behind: `(bool) FindResource("MyBool")`

*More specifically how do I change its value when a button is clicked? And how do I bind to the boolean resource, so when its value changes, some codes will be executed? (Using Triggers?)*

You can't. For this you'll need to use a `DependencyProperty`, not a `Resource`.

*Note: I do not want any code-behinds, I wish to do this in pure XAML.*

As mentioned, you'll need a bit of code-behind if you have to declare a dependency property. It's nice get to as much of the UI plumbing as possible done in XAML, but when defining data and business logic you need to go code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try with DynamicResource ,I think then you can change the value of resource.